# ionic Angular to Android Api connection issue

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework

```
{
   "headers":{
      "normalizedNames":{ 
      },
      "lazyUpdate":null,
      "headers":{
         
      }
   },
   "status":0,
   "statusText":"Unknown Error",
   "url":"http://dev6-pc:8085/api/users",
   "ok":false,
   "name":"HttpErrorResponse",
   "message":"Http failure response for http://dev6-pc:8085/api/users: 0 Unknown Error",
   "error":{
      "isTrusted":true
   }
}
```

my angular ionic is working perfect in web application but taking it to ionic android it through me error

i am trying to login user with api but in android it get fail

Comment: I had find the solution for this .....